# Tradingview PINE script - Plot extended session H/L that can be transferred to regular session

Tags: pine-script, stock, tradingview-api

My question to experts:

Indicators to plot H/L for extended session are available. I trade on regular session time frame but would like to see the pre-market H/L. Currently, in extended session i drop horizontal lines on H/L, then i can see them in regular session. On 15 thumbnail charts this is cumbersome as my horizontal lines are static and hence do not track extended session price - basically whack a mole moving h-lines. Is there method to add h-lines based on PM H/L levels, track price until open, then make visible during regular hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using `request.security()`. This is the example how get high from ETH:

```
//@version=5
indicator("request.security")
h = request.security(ticker.modify(syminfo.tickerid, session.extended), timeframe.period, high)
plot(h)
plot(high)
```

Keep in mind this is just example. You need finalize it for your needs yourself